# Automatically update package

Tags: r, github, devtools

I have written an R package, hosted on Github, that I would like users to always run the most up-to-date version.  What is the best practice for checking within R, preferably at package loading, if there is a newer version? And if there is a newer version to download and install it.

I know I can get the current installed version using `packageVersion('MyPackage')`.

I guess one way to get the repository version number would be to download the DESCRIPTION file, and use some regex to search for the version number.  But is there a better way?

Having established that an update is available, is there then a safe way to install it from within the same package at loading.  For example having something like

```
if (github_ver > installed_ver) {
  install_github('MyRepository/MyPackage')
}
```

embedded in the `.onLoad()` hook? Although this way looks risky to me.

Comment: I think its a bad idea to automatically install anything. Maybe throw a prompt? The only package I can think of that warns about out-of-date versions is `devtools`. Try looking at [devtools::dr_devtools](https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/blob/master/R/doctor.R)?

Comment: thanks @jsta - in many cases you are right automating the update may not be recommended.  But in this case, the only people running the package are using it to interface with and process data from a specific piece of laboratory analytical equipment, and they really should be running the updates.  PS, TY for the devtools link, it's useful.  Seems that devtools saves a specific file with the version number, so only the url needs to be queried to find the updated version

Comment: I know that many packages in BioC check to see if a more recent version is available as a source package. You might look at the code that does that.